# Add a few letters of text before a list item

Tags: lists, itemize, description

I currently have a small list, where the outline spacing is pretty important. Currently I have this short list:

[image: as is]

However I want the 'accent' to be only on the D, so that I get something like this:

[image: should be]

I currently have the following bit of text/code, though I don't quite see how I can manage this.

```
\begin{description}
  \item[C]ommon infrastructure  

  \item[L]ocation independence 

  \item[O]nline accessibility

  \item[U]tility pricing

  \item[on-D]mand resources 

\end{description}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
  \item[C]ommon infrastructure

  \item[L]ocation independence

  \item[O]nline accessibility

  \item[U]tility pricing

  \item[\llap{on-}D]mand resources

\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that will do the trick. Thank you very much! I'll accept your answer as soon as possible.

Comment: I'd prefer `\makebox[0pt][r]{on-}` or `\makebox[0pt][r]{\normalfont on-}`. In this case `\llap` behaves well, in other cases it could lead to surprising results.

Comment: @egreg: They are cases where I sacrifice the LaTeX-purety to shorter typing --especially when I'm using the screen keyboard of my tablet.;-). Btw.: around your code a layer of braces are needed.